# pine script error- An argument of 'series string' type was used but a 'const string' is expected

Tags: pine-script

when I am trying to pass date to timestamp() function I am getting error "Cannot call 'timestamp' with argument 'dateString'='date_bluex5'. An argument of 'series string' type was used but a 'const string' is expected"

what can be the solution for this. How can I convert a series string to a constant string?

Following is the code I used

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")
box_plot_found_blue=ta.crossover(close,ta.sma(close,200))
int yrx5 = ta.valuewhen(box_plot_found_blue, dayofmonth(time), 5)
int mox5 = ta.valuewhen(box_plot_found_blue, month(time), 5)
int dax5 = ta.valuewhen(box_plot_found_blue, year(time), 5)

date_bluex5 = str.tostring(math.round(yrx5)) + '/' + str.tostring(math.round(mox5)) + '/' + str.tostring(math.round(dax5))

targetTime = timestamp(date_bluex5)
bgcolor(targetTime == time ? color.silver : na)
```

how can I convert a series string to a constant string?

Comment: Don't ask the same question in multiple forums. You risk getting different volunteers helping you concurrently.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65928792/pine-script-seriesstring-to-string-conversion, apperaently there's not way to cast a "series string" to a const string

Answer (score 2):

I have found out the solution to my problem and posting the code so that can help others. Basically I was passing the wrong variable in timestamp , the following input format is correct and it helped me in resolving the error.

The error was resolved by directly passing the integer value to the timestamp() function as in the below attached code.

also updated bgcolor() statement and used a range of time because time == t1 is true for only one micro second and it’s false for rest of her time. It will change bgcolor of one bar only if that microsecond is equal to bar open/close time I believe. When using time, always use range. Such as time less than something and more than something.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Test script",overlay=true)
box_plot_found_blue=ta.crossover(close,ta.sma(close,200))
plot(ta.sma(close,200))
//bgcolor(box_plot_found_blue?color.red:na)
int dax5  = ta.valuewhen(box_plot_found_blue, dayofmonth(time), 2)
int mox5 = ta.valuewhen(box_plot_found_blue, month(time), 2)
int yrx5 = ta.valuewhen(box_plot_found_blue, year(time), 2)

t1 = timestamp(yrx5, mox5, dax5, 00, 00)
t2 = timestamp(yrx5, mox5, dax5+1, 00, 00) 

bgcolor( (time >= t1) and (time <= t2) ? color.silver : na)
```

Comment: How is this the solution when [timestamp](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_timestamp) returns an int?

Comment: basically i was passing the wrong variable in timestamp , the above input format was correct and it helped me in resolving the error.